# How to integration OrientDB in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, orientdb

OrientDB dart dependency get the error

C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color packages get
Stack dump aborted because of no current Dart thread.
Process finished with exit code 3

How to solve the issue.

Comment: this package not compatible with dart2

Comment: So, What can I do?

Comment: you can fill issue in repository or find another package, for example `sqflite`